# Node.js restify with socket.io

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket, socket.io, restify

Is it possible to run socket.io & restify on the same port like express & socket.io?

I did just like this but it didn't work

```
# server.coffee
restify = require 'restify'
socket  = require 'socket.io'

server = restify.createServer()

io = socket.listen server
server.listen 1337
```

when I try to connect to socket.io:

```
GET http://localhost:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 25):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/issues/230) by @jtomasrl and @zacheryph, this worked for me:

```
var server = restify.createServer();
var io = socketio.listen(server.server); //Note server.server instead of just server
```

Comment: Up 1. Real and helpful answer.

Comment: `server.server`! ah!

Comment: simple and helpful

Answer (score 10):

Since this is the first google hit for "restify socket.io" I'm posting a new answer.  This works fine now as documented at http://restify.com/docs/home/#socketio

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, using socket.io with restify is not possible yet: https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/issues/230

Comment: @Sitapati Das They added the feature, take a look at Socket.IO section: http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/